Medical - Must use corrective lens(es)…
Recently went to Flight Safety for the first time and one of the instructors was talking about the time he got ramp-checked and they asked him after looking at his medical if he had his two pairs of glasses on board. I can’t find a regulation anywhere that requires you to have two different sets. Is that a company requirement normally or am I missing the regulation somewhere?
I normally wear contacts with a backup pair of glasses and want to make sure I am legal in my 135. Not seeing anything in the GOM or Ops that would require anything beyond the FAA and ICAO requirement.

For domestic flights, it's recommended but not required. For oceanic or international flights it's required under ICAO rules. The FAA published an InFO document on the topic here.
The ICAO requirements are in Annex 1:

Where this standard of visual acuity can be obtained
only with correcting lenses, the applicant may be assessed as fit provided that:
a) such correcting lenses are worn during the exercise of the privileges of the licence or rating applied for or held; and
b) in addition, a pair of suitable correcting spectacles is kept readily available during the exercise of the privileges of the
applicant’s licence.

So you need to be wearing a set of lenses (i.e. contacts are fine) and have a spare pair of spectacles (i.e. contacts are not fine for the spare). One pair of contacts and one pair of eyeglasses are fine as long as you're wearing the contacts.

Correct, I saw that as well but didn’t know if that meant that I was required to bring my contacts and two sets of glasses or just the contacts and the glasses I normally bring as well. My understanding would be that I am good with contacts and one set of spare lenses but don't want to be caught out. Appreciate the help.

@JonathanWilkinson Contacts and spare glasses are fine per ICAO. You should of course make sure the country you're flying in doesn't have stricter laws.

And, of course, always have at least one spare set of contacts just in case you loose/tear one. Sure, you may finish this flight with the glasses, but you wear contacts because (most likely) you prefer them.
